# Show the measure is finite

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\{\mu_n\}$ be measures on $(X,M)$ with $\sup\{\mu_n\} \leq M < \infty$.

Let $\mu = \sum_{n \geq 1 } 2^{-n} \mu_n$

Show that $\mu$ is a finite measure.

Attempt:

It's easily verified that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$.

For countable additivity,

Let $(E_k) \subset M$ be disjoint. Then we have $$\mu (\cup_{k\geq 1} E_n)= \sum_{n \geq 1 } 2^{-n} \mu_n(\cup_{k \geq 1 }E_k)= \sum_{n \geq 1 } 2^{-n} (\sum_{k\geq 1}\mu_n(E_k))= \sum_{k\geq 1}(\sum_{n \geq 1} 2^{-n} \mu_n (E_k)) = \sum_{k\geq 1} \mu(E_k)$$

The part I'm having trouble is the finiteness of $\mu$. I know that $\sum_{n \geq 1} 2^{-n}=1$. But why do we have $\sum_{n\geq 1} \mu_n < \infty$ from $\sup\{\mu_n\} \leq M < \infty$?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using M as a $\sigma$-algebra and as a real number?

Comment: For example, you're using $M$ as a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, but $\mathbb{sup}\{\mu_n \} \le M$, and $M$ is a real number. I am confused there. Why not using $\mathcal{A}$ instead of $M$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to use the Weierstrass M test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test.

Define $\lambda_n : = 2^{-n} \mu_n$ and note that
\begin{equation*}
\lambda_n = 2^{-n} \mu_n \leq 2^{-n} M, \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\ .
\end{equation*}
Now, observe that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n}M = M \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n} \right)\ .
\end{equation}
Therefore, the series the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n}M$ converges, i. e.,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n}M < \infty\ .
\end{equation}
Then by the weierstrass M test the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda_n$ converges, i. e.,
\begin{equation}
\mu = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n}\mu_n < \infty.
\end{equation}